# Website down after changing permalinks to postname

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

just spent quite some time searching on Google and Stack Overflow for my problem, changed the .htaccess already but no changes.
I changed the permalink settings to postname, saved, refreshed my site and got the error: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache Server at arnoldnumerouno.de Port 80

After searching I changed the .htaccess to:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

--

The page is still down and I can't access the wp-admin to set it to default again.

I really need some help :-( Just spent several hours on writing posts and now the page is down and I have no clue what to do.

Really appreciate any help from you guys,
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you modified any server settings? Have you touched the .conf files?

Comment: This doesn't really seem an optimal question for Stack Overflow. Wouldn't it be best suited for Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: Didnt touch any .conf files.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing:

`SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3`

Also, make sure that your files and directories have the proper permissions: 755 for directories, 644 for files.

**EDIT**

Also, try adding the following to the beginning of your .htaccess:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Hey, removed it, no changes. Sry im quite new to this so I dont know where Im supposed to change those permissions, can you help me out here? :-)

Comment: This is the Codex page you should refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions . Simply use your FTP software to set those permissions on all of the directories and files, recursively - 755 for directories, 644 for files.

Answer (score 0):

When generating new permalinks,
if you have the wrong site url and home url settings,
wordpress will give an error like:

*You don't have permission to access / on this server*

(...actually it's not finding the directory),

if you've changed them recently, I suggest you check.

---

to edit site url and home url directly in database use phpmyadmin,

change **siteurl** and **home** row in the **option** table